# Assign the value of a loop index(increment) to a variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash, loops, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I just started learning `bash`, and currently stuck on something.

In Java and other programming languages, we are able to assign the value of the loop variable `i` to another variable, for example:

```
for(int i = 0; i<=5; i++){sum=i^3;}
```

I've been trying to do that in `bash`,

```
for i in {1..$1}
  do
  for j in {1..$2}
   do
sum=$((i**3+j**3))
```

and I also tried this,

```
sum=$(($i**3+$j**3))
```

but both gave me the same error:

```
$ Dio.sh 2 3 1 5
Dio.sh: line 11: {1..3}**3: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{1..3}**3")
```

What am I missing?

Comment: the `{1..$1}` will not work because brace expansion happens before variable expansion, so you're left with a literal `$1` once the loop is done. The only way it should work is with `eval` but that is not the way to do it. The cfor style loop is fine, just assign it in a varialbe. `i=$1 `j=$2`.

Comment: The bash `for` loop is used with lists, like `for i in $(seq 1 3)`, and arithmetic is done like `(( ++i ))`.

Answer (score 1):

You do it nearly the same way your would in Java.

```
for ((i = 1; i <= $1; i++)); do
    ...
done
```

Brace expansion is meant for interactive use, and does not expand parameters.

Answer (score 0):

this is one way of doing it

```
$ sum=0; for i in {1..10}; do ((sum+=i*i*i)); done; echo $sum
3025
```

but probably `bash` is not the right tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

For-loops can also be written as such:

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=$(( 0 ))
for (( i=1; i<=5; i++ ))
do 
        sum=$(( $sum+i*i*i ))
        echo "Sum is: $sum"

        for (( j=1; j<=5; j++ ))
        do 
                sum=$(( $sum+j*j*j ))
                echo "Sum is: $sum"
        done

done
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the code you first presented in your question had the following line:

```
sum=$((i3+j3))
```

which, based on the error you attached, was a typo; in this respect your question was edited in such a way that that line becomes

```
sum=$((i**3+j**3))
```

which is likely the one in your script.

Apart from this, your question has only been formatted a bit better, without changing anything significan.

However, the script was still wrong for the simple reason it does not contain the closing `done` for none of the two `for` loops:

```
for i in {1..$1}
  do
  for j in {1..$2}
   do
sum=$((i**3+j**3))
  done # this was missing
done # this was missing
```

Trying to execute this script **without** the `done` lines should generate the error:

```
./yourfile.sh: line theLine: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

However, since you show another error, I deduce that you actually put the two `done`s in your script, and that you only forgot them in the question.

So we end up with your code being the following:

```
for i in {1..$1}; do
  for j in {1..$2}; do
    sum=$((i**3+j**3))
  done
done
```

which gives the error you shared, for the reason explained by Jetchisel in a comment:

> The `{1..$1}` will not work because brace expansion happens before variable expansion, so you're left with a literal `$1` once the loop is done.

This is to answer the question *What am I missing?*.

Ways of doing it the right way are explained in other answers.